# If statements with undefined variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong I tried to define "if the answer was `'Y'` Then `premium_membership=true`" but I keep getting this error. The beginning is as far as I get when I run the code and the second is my code.

```
What is your name? John Smith 
How many books are you purchasing today? 5
Are you apart of our membership program? Enter Y for yes or N for No. N
Would you like to join our membership program for $4.95? Enter Y for yes or N for no. N
Thank you for your interest, and thanks for shopping with us!

John Smith 
The customer is purchasing 5.0 books
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File , line 41, in <module>
    if premium_member==True:
    NameError: name 'premium_member' is not defined
>>>
```

---

```
#ask what customer's name is
customer_name=input("What is your name?")

#ask customer how many books they are purchasing
#define answer as float so you can multiply by price later
books_purchased=float(input("How many books are you purchasing today?"))

#ask customer if they are a member
membership=input("Are you apart of our membership program? Enter Y for yes or N for No.")

#determine if and print if member or not
if membership =='Y':
    premium_member=True
else:
    join=input("Would you like to join our membership program for $4.95? Enter Y for yes or N for no.")

#define join
if join =='Y':
    print("Thank you for joining our Membership Program!")

else:
    print("Thank you for your interest, and thanks for shopping with us!")

#print name
print("\n",customer_name)

#print number of books purchased
print("The customer is purchasing", books_purchased, "books")

#determine if they customer is premium 
if premium_member==True:
    print("Premium Member")
else:
    print("Regular Member")       

#determine if customer gets any free books
if premium_member==True:
    if book_purchased>9:
        print("Congratulations you get two books for free!")
        total_books=book_purchased+2
    else:
        if book_purchased >6 and book_purchased<=9:
            print("Congratulations you get one book for free!")
            total_books=books_purchased+1
        else:
            total_books=books_purchased
else:
    if books_purchased>12:
            print("Congratulations you get two books for free!")
            total_books=book_purchased+2
    else:
        if books_purchased >8 and books_purchased <=12:
            print("Congratulations you get one book for free!")
            total_books=book_purchased+1
        else:
            total_books=books_purchased
```

Comment: Next time you have this sort of problem, take the error you get, and remove the variablename and plug it into google, like this: "python NameError: name  is not defined", the first five links, properly understood will tell you why you are getting this error.  Also, you need to revisit the core python tutorial of scope around if statements, how the line of execution advances through a python program, and "what happens when  you use a variable without defining it?"

Answer (score 4):

In this section of code

```
if membership =='Y':
    premium_member=True
else:
    join=input("Would you like to join our membership program for $4.95? Enter Y for yes or N for no.")
```

you're assigning `premium_member=True` in the case that `membership` is equal to `'Y'` but in the case that it's not (the `else` branch) you aren't assigning a value at all, meaning that the variable will be undefined. You should add the line `premium_member=False` to the `else` branch.

```
if membership =='Y':
    premium_member=True
else:
    premium_member=False
    join=input("Would you like to join our membership program for $4.95? Enter Y for yes or N for no.")
```

Comment: While this will fix the problem, I see it as bad practice to define a variable only in `if` statements. Better practice is to define it outside the `if` statements and assign a value in the `if` statement.

Comment: I agree with you on this, but the advice on where to initialize depends a lot on the context. In this case, since the value being assigned is boolean and corresponds exactly to the branch, I would probably go with `premium_member = membership == 'Y'` followed by `if not premium_member: join = ...`